# Preencher os parâmetros do Array args sem sair do Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Eu possuo parâmetros que são passados ao executar o .jar do meu código, em `args`, como nesse exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final File diretorio = new File(args[0]);
        final String extencao = "." + args[1];
        final String origem = "\\"+args[2];
        final String destino = "\\"+args[3];
```

Quero saber se é possível eu definir os valores que estou passando na linha de comando pelo o Eclipse, sem precisar alterar os valores das variáveis ou chamar separadamente pelo console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conforme retirado [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/374220/5524514), as instruções abaixo é para o caso de você já ter executado sua classe que possui o método main ao menos 1 vez dentro da IDE:

- No menu, clique em `Run` , depois em `Run Configurations...`. Vai aparecer uma tela semelhante a esta:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

---

- na lista suspensa na lateral, procure pelo nome da sua classe que quer passar parâmetros no main, no meu caso, é a classe que já está selecionada, `MainParametrosTest`.

---

- clique na guia `Arguments` e aparecerá conforme o print abaixo:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

No campo `Program Arguments`, você irá inserir os argumentos que quer passar para o main da sua classe separados por um espaço.

Veja o exemplo abaixo, onde passei `argumento1 argumento2 argumento3`:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo.